# PHP output выводит мусор

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

На macOS все работает отлично:

```
<?php
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
print_r($array);
?>
```

соответственно получаем:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )
```

Но на WIndows 10 RUS получаю:

> [Running] php "c:\Users\s.sergeev\Documents\WorkSpace\array_1.php"
> "php" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
> ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

В настройках стоит UTF-8, PHP Debug стоит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: откуда вывод взят?

Comment: Visual Studio Code, добавил картинку

Comment: Пересохрани в кодировку утф 8 или ср1251

Comment: На рисунке видно что он создан и открыт в UTF-8, но я попробовал и так и так, ничего не меняется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Мусор", как вы выразились - это всего лишь то, что ваш VS Code вам просто пишет "php не является внутренней или  внешней командой", потому что у вас либо PHP не установлен, либо установлен, но не виден в переменной PATH. Если установлен, то можете также указать VS Code в настройках явный путь до php.exe, например

`"php.executablePath": "c:\\php\\php.exe",`

Что касается "мусора", то это ваш эмулятор терминала (я думаю, это плагин Code Runner), то вам желательно изменить настройки в системе (для не-Unicode).

Введите в cmd следующее и потом Enter

`chcp`

Открываете Панель управления\Все элементы панели управления выбираете Региональные стандарты => Дополнительно => Язык программ, не поддерживающих Юникод => Изменить язык системы и поставить "Россия". Перезагружаетесь. Смотрите на `chcp` опять.

Также, есть шанс, что у вас для cmd не выбран правильный шрифт. В настройках постарайтесь выбрать что-то с Unicode (возможно, кто-то что-то уже менял) - например, Lucida Console, Cascadia.

Comment: Региональные стандарты => Дополнительно => Язык программ, не поддерживающих Юникод => Изменить язык системы и поставил "Россия" и также поставил галку Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире. Кодировка chcp с 866 поменялась на 65001, текст теперь читается, именно тот, что вы написали выше: php не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: Отлично. Теперь "пропишите" PHP любым описанным выше способом.

Comment: Сделал, спасибо! Все работает как надо )